# Pattern matching in a scala method without arguments

Tags: scala

I recently looked into scala multithreading tutorials and stumbled on a method which is implemented in an Actor:

```
class MyActor extends Actor
  def receive = {
    case "test" => println("received test")
    case _ =>      println("received unknown message")
  }
}
```

Although I think I know what the method does, I can't figure out how to use such a method (at it does not take any arguments).

Althouh the example is about Akka, I think this is unrelated to Akka

Comment: Could you drop documentation link as well? Looks like it going to do pattern matching against message received.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually `receive` returns partial function. When you check the source code of `Actor` you'll see that;

```
type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
```

So it means with overriding receive you're providing a partial function which takes any parameter and return unit. At some point later, if your actor gets a message Akka itself will use this partial function to do pattern match over the incoming message.

-- Edit --

For more concrete example, let say you created a similar object;

```
object Obj {
  def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case "test" => println("test case")
    case 1 => println("int 1 case")
    case d: Double => println("double case $d")
    case _ => println("rest")
  }
}
```

Then you can call this partial function like regular method call;

```
scala> Obj.receive(1)
int 1 case
scala> Obj.receive("test")
test case
```

Actor case is specific, it's just that you don't call the receive directly, you provide it and Akka itself calls it if the messages arrive;

```
protected[akka] def aroundReceive(receive: Actor.Receive, msg: Any): Unit = receive.applyOrElse(msg, unhandled)
```

Of course this call depends on lots of parameters like the topology you use,mailbox and etc.

Comment: I still don't see how I can get this method to do something (independently of Akka). Can you provide some code on how to invoke `receive`, I mean such that it actually prints something?

Comment: Ok now I get it, you have the explicitly define the return type `def receive : PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`, otherwise its not working in plain standard scala. In my above example the return type is defined in `trait Actor`, therefore you don't need to specify it again as you implement the method

Answer (score 1):

As @Fatih Donmez said, it's a *Parital Funciton*, this defined certain values of certain types, usage:

```
List("hello", "test").foreach {
    case "test" => println("received test")
    case _ =>      println("received unknown message")
}

(0 to 20) collect {
    case i if i % 2 == 0 => i
}

(0 to 20) map {
    case i if i % 2 == 0 => i * i
    case j => j
}
```

also you can use it directly, like:

```
val f1: PartialFunction[Int, Unit] = {
   case 1 => println("I am 1")
   case t => println(s"I am $t")
}

f1(1)

> I am 1

f1(2)

> I am 2
```

**orElse** Example:

```
val f1: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
   case i if i % 2 == 0 => i * i
}

val f2: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
   case i if i % 2 != 0 => i+1
}

val f = f1 orElse f2

f(1)
> 2

(0 to 10) map f
> scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 2, 4, 4, 16, 6, 36, 8, 64, 10, 100)
```

**andThen** Example:

```
val f1: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
   case i if i % 2 == 0 => i * i
   case j => j
}

val f2: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
   case i if i % 2 != 0 => i * i
   case j => j + 1
}

val f = f1 andThen f2
f(2)
res20: Int = 5

(0 to 10) map f
> scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 5, 9, 17, 25, 37, 49, 65, 81, 101)
```

**compose** Example:

```
val f1: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
   case i if i % 2 == 0 => i * i
   case j => j
}

val f2: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
   case i if i % 2 != 0 => i * i
   case j => j + 1
}


val f = f1 compose f2

f(2)
res18: Int = 3

(0 to 10) map f
res17: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 3, 9, 5, 25, 7, 49, 9, 81, 11)
```

docs:

1. https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/pattern-matching-and-functional-composition.html
2. https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/pattern-matching-and-functional-composition.html